# Installing EPEL on RHEL

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I'm running RHEL version 6.7 on a server, and am having trouble installing [EPEL](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-epel-repository-on-centos.html).

Since I'm running RHEL version 6.7 I was told I needed a 6.x version of EPEL. So I installed:

```
epel-release-6-8.noarch
```

However, after installing, every time I would run a 'yum' command, it would return the error

```
xz compression not available
```

So I had to uninstall.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your `tar` version?

Comment: Be aware that xz works only from tar [1.22  (march 2009)](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/).

Comment: @FarazX , I have version 1.23 , do I need to downgrade? Thanks

Comment: no not at all! I'm going to write you an answer with all steps needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read this [article](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1099676) since it can help you much.

All you need, is to do steps below:

- First of all, remove epel-release: `yum remove epel-release`
- Then, delete it from `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel` or the 32 bit version if your system is 32 bit, and then you need to install the correct epel-release package. So download the correct epel-release RPM - the one which suits your system architecture - and then install it.
- Finally, you should install `pyliblzma` since that will allow the RHEL6 yum to handle the xz repodata specially those used in epel.

  `yum install pyliblzma`

And then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the `epel-release`:

```
yum remove epel-release
```

Remove the cached files for epel under `/var/cache/yum/...`

Then enable EPEL Repository:

**RHEL 6 32-Bit**

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

**RHEL 6 64-Bit**

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this after making sure I have the right version of tar installed (currently: 1.23)